# Alternatives to Spring's deprecated ExpressionEvaluationUtils evaluate methods?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Since the class:[org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils.html)
is deprecated since Spring 3.x release, I am looking for another alternative for EL expression evaluation in my java code.

After reading JSP 2.x documentation, I did manage to construct an alternative method:

```
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory;
import javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext;


public class ExpressionEvaluationUtils {


    public static Object evaluate(String exp, Class<?> resultClass, PageContext pageContext)
        throws JspException {

        if (pageContext == null){
            return exp;
        }
        ELContext elContext =  pageContext.getELContext();
        JspFactory jf = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
        JspApplicationContext jac = jf
                         .getJspApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext());
        ExpressionFactory ef = jac.getExpressionFactory();
        ValueExpression val = ef.createValueExpression(elContext, exp, resultClass);
        return val.getValue(elContext);
    }

}
```

Can you suggest more alternatives to my implementation?

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils.html)? - as of Spring 3.2, in favor of the JSP 2.0+ native support for embedded expressions in JSP pages (also applying to tag attributes)

Comment: I did, the native support works flawlessly. But sometimes I am evaluating the expression directly.

Comment: So, can you use [ExpressionFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html)?

Comment: I am using it in my code above. I am curious about another solutions.

Comment: @MaximKirilov Thank you for sharing this method. How do you use the class? Where should I insert it and call it? Thank you.

Comment: @maxim-kirilov  How would you deal with the original parameters of the method? The original class has String paramName, String paramValue. How do I get String exp out of these, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any of the projects below:

- [Apache Commons OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/)
- [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/)
- [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.2.GA/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html)
- [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions)