# spring replace class ExpressionEvaluationUtils

Tags: spring, expression-evaluation

I have the following code and I migrated my project from spring 3 to spring 4.
But ExpressionEvaluationUtils is obsolete actually.
Do you have any idea to replace it ?

```
/**
 * Set quote escaping for this tag, as boolean value. Default is "true".
 */
public void setQuoteEscape(String quoteEscape) throws JspException {
    this.quoteEscape = ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluateBoolean("quoteEscape", quoteEscape, pageContext);
}

/**
 * Set breakLine escaping for this tag, as boolean value. Default is "true".
 */
public void setBackslashEscape(String backslashEscape) throws JspException {
    this.backslashEscape = ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluateBoolean("backslashEscape", backslashEscape, pageContext);
}
```

Do you have any idea to replace it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Spring's deprecated ExpressionEvaluationUtils evaluate methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547637/alternatives-to-springs-deprecated-expressionevaluationutils-evaluate-methods)